# Configuring Android Studio in multiple PCs without use of separate SDKs

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to configure Android Studio for 10 PC. how i configure that from existing SDK. Is there a need to download separate SDK for 10 PC?

Comment: zip the whole sdk folder and copy it to the desired pc and unzip it as simple as.

Comment: Put the SDK on a share drive and point Android studio to the shared location.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share why you want to have the same SDK for 10 pc? The benefit I can get is to reduce the total download time.

If I get ur question, you can have several options:

1. Compress the existing sdk folder, and use USB/LAN to share the 
   compressed file (ex. andorid_sdk.zip), and decompress it to the path you want. you can have ur own path convention to make 10 PCs follow. And don't forget to set Android Studio SDK path well.
2. Create a network shared folder and mount it on the same path for 10pcs, and they can have the really same one SDK sharing. Though I didnt try it and I don't recommend it cause maybe someone mess up the sdk, and all suffers.

If you want to configure SDK in this way cause of development courses. I think you should let them to download sdk separately in 10 PCs and do those steps by themselves. That way they can learn how to setup development environment.

Btw, Android Studio will provide better SDK integration in the future Stable release (From 2015 Gooogle IO Conference).

Hope these infos can help you.